# When was the Higg's particle created after the Big Bang?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, space-expansion, higgs, big-bang

Was the Higg's particle created with the Bag Bang?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the existence of the Higgs is part of the standard model of physics  so it  "existed" when the model is successful in describing cosmological data. See my answer here for this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/723705/what-order-did-the-particles-of-nature-appear-in/723710#723710